# ASP.NET Parameter passing from program to Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am currently passing 3 values into my stored procedure for it to run. However my stored procedure contain 5 parameters. Just wondering do I need to pass all 5 values in order for it to work or 3 will do?

I am also facing this issue [image]

Wondering if this error is caused by I'm passing NULL values into my Stored Procedure? Thanks in advance.

## Edit

Below are the definition in my stored procedure as requested:

```
create or replace procedure upd_pre_proc_card
(prodOrderNo in varchar2,
userId      in varchar2,
poDate      in varchar2, /* poDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd' */
orderType   in varchar2,
printOption in number)
```

Comment: It depends on the definition of the parameters in the stored procedure, which you didn't post here, so we can't tell for sure.

Comment: And please **also show us** how you call this stored procedure from your code in ASP.NET !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario (the stored procedure that you provided), yes you need to provide all the parameters. I believe in Oracle you can specify the default value for a parameter so something like:

```
create or replace procedure upd_pre_proc_card
(prodOrderNo in varchar2,
userId      in varchar2,
poDate      in varchar2 default null, /* is optional now */
orderType   in varchar2,
printOption in number)
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be because of null values or null values being passed wrong into the stored procedure heres how you should check each value before assigning it to a parameter.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderType))
{
   Parameters.Add([AddYourValuesHere).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
   Parameters.Add([AddYourValuesHere]).Value = orderType;
}
```